# Fit an exponential decay model in R

Tags: r

I am very new to R and I appreciate the help

I have some data that looks like this.

[image]

Y is negatively correlated with X, in a nonlinear way. It seems to be approximated by a formula of the following form  *y=1+a<sup>x</sup>* where *a<1*.

If I wanted to fit that data in R to find *a* what function would I use? NLS?

Comment: Yes, `nls` is worth using.  Something like: `nls(y ~ b+ a^x, data = mydata, start = list(b = 1, a = 0.5))` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Next time please provide test data.  We have done it for you this time.  Then we use `nls` as shown.

```
set.seed(123)

# generate test data
n <- 35
x <- 1:n
a <- 0.5
y <- 1 + a^x + rnorm(n, 0, .01)

fm <- nls(y ~ 1+a^x, start = list(a = mean((y-1)^(1/x), na.rm = TRUE)))
fm
```

giving:

```
Nonlinear regression model
  model: y ~ 1 + a^x
   data: parent.frame()
     a 
0.5025 
 residual sum-of-squares: 0.003031

Number of iterations to convergence: 5 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 1.346e-06
```

### Plot

```
plot(y ~ x)
lines(fitted(fm) ~ x, col = "red")
```

[image: screenshot]